# Qt: c++: QTableView does not display my Model

Tags: c++, qt, model, qtableview

I am creating a `model` using this code:

```
QStandardItemModel table_model(4,4);
    for(int row=0; row<4; row++){
        for (int column=0; column<4; column++){
            QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem((QString("100")));
            table_model.setItem(row,column,item);
        }
    }
```

Then, I am passing it to `QTableView` as follow:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = &table_model;
ui->table->setModel(model);
ui->table->show();
```

However something is wrong. The `QTableView` shows nothing, just white space all over it. yet, if, and only if, I click on the trigger button (which creates the model and links it to the `QTableView`) I can see the 4x4 table, and yet without any data. immediately after the "click" everything disappear (it is just the moment of clicking the button) ..

so what am I missing ? – thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create your model on stack and pass a pointer which gets invalid right after you leave method where you declare it.

```
QStandardItemModel * table_model = new QStandardItemModel(4,4);
```